# European Transit Visa

Tags: schengen, transit, europe, missed-flights, palestine-citizens

If I missed my flight to Moscow in Amsterdam (Transit), can I book again while in transit to Moscow with transit in Copenhagen, Denmark?
Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but without any relevant information (citizenship, present legal status in Amsterdam) no answer can be given.

Comment: and? What is your legal status now in Amsterdam?

Comment: Thanks for replying, citizenship is Palestinian, having a Russian Visa, flying from Beirut, Lebanon to Moscow with transit in Amsterdam. Missed my flight while in the transit area of Amsterdam, is it possible to book again from Amsterdam to Moscow with transit in Copenhagen? In this situation do I need a tranist Visa?

Comment: If you have no Schengen Visa, you may **not** take an internal flight to Copenhagen. I assume you have not passed the passport control? You must then take a direct flight outside of the Schengen Area.

Comment: Yeah I didn't, thank ypu so much for the info! Have a good day)